# SQL max last_Update column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, max

I am looking for help with the below update query. I am trying to update the `provreg` table with the latest updated contract from the contractinfo table but it doesn't seem right.  What is the best way to complete this update using the max(lastupdate) field on the contractinfo table?

```
UPDATE provreg
SET ContractName = ci.ContractID,
    ContractBegin = ci.ContractEff,
    ContractEnd = ci.contractterm
FROM provreg pr
INNER JOIN Provider P ON pr.npi = p.npi
INNER JOIN Affiliation A ON a.provid = p.provid
INNER JOIN contractinfo ci ON ci.affiliationid = a.affiliationid
WHERE CI.CONTRACTED = 'Y'
  AND ci.lastupdate = (SELECT MAX(lastupdate)
                       FROM contractinfo 
                       WHERE contractid = ci.contractid)
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That syntax is no ANSI SQL.)

Comment: SSMS, i changed the last statement in where, I originally posted the wrong query as I was trying different ways.

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data and expected output on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/)?

Answer (score 0):

Try below.

```
UPDATE PROVREG
   SET (CONTRACTNAME, CONTRACTBEGIN, CONTRACTEND) =
          (SELECT CI.CONTRACTID, CI.CONTRACTEFF, CI.CONTRACTTERM
             FROM PROVREG PR
                  INNER JOIN PROVIDER P ON PR.NPI = P.NPI
                  INNER JOIN AFFILIATION A ON A.PROVID = P.PROVID
                  INNER JOIN CONTRACTINFO CI
                     ON CI.AFFILIATIONID = A.AFFILIATIONID
            WHERE     CI.CONTRACTED = 'Y'
                  AND CI.LASTUPDATE = (SELECT MAX (LASTUPDATE)
                                         FROM PLANREPORT_QNXT_LA.DBO.CONTRACTINFO
                                        WHERE CONTRACTID = CI.CONTRACTID));

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Getting: 
Incorrect syntax near '('

at the first open parenthesis after SET